# log type 'client' not found in pytest selenium

Tags: selenium, logging, selenium-chromedriver, pytest, desiredcapabilities

```
 logs = selenium.driver.get_log('client')
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: log type 'client' not found
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.88)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

I have set the desired capabilities:

```
dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
dc['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL',
                           'driver': 'ALL',
                           'client': 'ALL',
                           'server': 'ALL',
                           'performance': 'ALL'}
```

Please note `logs = selenium.driver.get_log('browser')` works fine

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: log type 'client' not found
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.88)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

...implies that though you are using *chrome=87.0.4280.88* but your *chromedriver* version is **2.38.552518** which old and ancient.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v87.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 87.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v87.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt)).
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.